# How to find students who is the third place?

Tags: r

I have data that shows every students' score and I have to find out who are in the third place. I have to make a list of test scores and a list of students' names.

If there are two or more people who get the same score and occupy third place, the output must show all of the names. I still have no idea how to solve this problem.

example :

```
names = c('Alex', 'Joy', 'Cindy', 'Lily')
score = c(80, 80,100,90)
```

Output:

```
'Students in the third place: Alex, Joy'.
```

Comment: Just find the min and if a tie return both ids? Not sure why you want third place though? Maybe just sort and get the indices?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `slice_max`, by default `with_ties = TRUE` and then `filter` the `min` value

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    slice_max(n = 3, order_by= score) %>% 
    filter(score == min(score))
```

-output

```
  names score
1  Alex    80
2   Joy    80
```

---

If we need to output in a `format`

```
df1 %>% 
    slice_max(n = 3, order_by= score) %>% 
    filter(score == min(score)) %>%
    pull(names) %>%
    {glue::glue("Students in the third place: {toString(.)}")}
Students in the third place: Alex, Joy
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(names, score)
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution with `rank`:

```
df$names[rank(-df$score) >= 3]
[1] "Alex" "Joy"
```

If you have ranks greater than 3:

```
df$names[rank(-df$score) >= 3 & rank(-df$score) <= 4]
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  names = c('Alex', 'Joy', 'Cindy', 'Lily'), 
  score = c(80, 80,100,90)
)
```